# How to generate a table from arp command output using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `arp` command output executed with Paramiko in a table format as shown below:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("arp")
opt = stdout.read().decode('ascii')
print(opt)

Address                 HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask    Iface(Ports)
0.00.00.00              ether       (incomplete)       C               eth0.1
0.00.00.00              ether       (incomplete)       C               eth0.2
0.00.00.00              ether   00:00:00:00:00:00      C             eth0.001(2)
0.00.00.00              ether   00:00:00:00:00:00      C             eth0.002(6)
```

Now, I wanted to read this table using pandas and wanted to display only few columns, I tried the below code but its not working for me.

```
    opt = io.StringIO(opt)
    df = pd.read_table(opt, sep='\s{2,}', usecols=[0,2,4], engine='python')
    print(df)

     Address              HWaddress         Iface(Ports)
0      00:00:00:00           eth0.1          None
1      00:00:00:00           eth0.2          None
2      00:00:00:00  00:00:00:00:00:00   eth0.001(2)
3      00:00:00:00  00:00:00:00:00:00   eth0.002(6)
```

As we can see in the above Dataframe output, wherever we have '(incomplete)' string that is replaced by Iface(Ports) column data. can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: if you have empty columns then maybe you should rather use `.read_fwf()` (fixed-width format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be simpler to use [read_fwf()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) (`fixed-width format`)

```
df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(text))
```

and later select columns

```
df = df[['Address','HWaddress', 'Iface(Ports)']]
```

---

Full example code:

```
text = '''Address                 HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask    Iface(Ports)
0.00.00.00              ether       (incomplete)       C               eth0.1
0.00.00.00              ether       (incomplete)       C               eth0.2
0.00.00.00              ether   00:00:00:00:00:00      C             eth0.001(2)
0.00.00.00              ether   00:00:00:00:00:00      C             eth0.002(6)
'''

import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(text))

print('--- full ---')
print(df)

df = df[['Address','HWaddress', 'Iface(Ports)']]

print('--- selected ---')
print(df)
```

Result:

```
--- full ---
      Address HWtype          HWaddress Flags  Mask Iface(Ports)
0  0.00.00.00  ether       (incomplete)     C   NaN       eth0.1
1  0.00.00.00  ether       (incomplete)     C   NaN       eth0.2
2  0.00.00.00  ether  00:00:00:00:00:00     C   NaN  eth0.001(2)
3  0.00.00.00  ether  00:00:00:00:00:00     C   NaN  eth0.002(6)
--- selected ---
      Address          HWaddress Iface(Ports)
0  0.00.00.00       (incomplete)       eth0.1
1  0.00.00.00       (incomplete)       eth0.2
2  0.00.00.00  00:00:00:00:00:00  eth0.001(2)
3  0.00.00.00  00:00:00:00:00:00  eth0.002(6)
```

---

**EDIT**

After getting DataFrame you can modify data useing pandas function - i.e. `.apply()`. You have strings so you can use string functions or regex.

```
def convert(item):
    if '(' in item:
        item = item.split('(')[1].split(')')[0]
    return item

df['Iface(Ports)'] = df['Iface(Ports)'].apply(convert)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
      Address          HWaddress Iface(Ports)
0  0.00.00.00       (incomplete)       eth0.1
1  0.00.00.00       (incomplete)       eth0.2
2  0.00.00.00  00:00:00:00:00:00            2
3  0.00.00.00  00:00:00:00:00:00            6
```

Comment: after creating dataframe you can do whatever you want with data in columns. You has strings in column so you can use string's functions to split on `(` and `)` and get number, or you can use `regex`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind doing some string parsing?

```
d = '''

Address                 HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask    Iface(Ports)
0.00.00.00              ether       (incomplete)       C               eth0.1
0.00.00.00              ether       (incomplete)       C               eth0.2
0.00.00.00              ether   00:00:00:00:00:00      C             eth0.001(2)
0.00.00.00              ether   00:00:00:00:00:00      C             eth0.002(6)

'''
```

removing empty lines

```
string  =[x for x in d.split('\n') if x != '']
```

Structuring data

```
data = []
for line in dd:
    data.append([x for x in line.split(' ') if x != ''])
```

Create dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
```

Sample output

```
0     Address HWtype          HWaddress Flags         Mask Iface(Ports)
1  0.00.00.00  ether       (incomplete)     C       eth0.1         None
2  0.00.00.00  ether       (incomplete)     C       eth0.2         None
3  0.00.00.00  ether  00:00:00:00:00:00     C  eth0.001(2)         None
4  0.00.00.00  ether  00:00:00:00:00:00     C  eth0.002(6)         None
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer srinath..but my problem is am not getting the same format in pandas dataframe output, as you can see the second code snippet in my question, I am using below line 
df = pd.read_table(opt, sep='\s{2,}', usecols=[0,2,4], engine='python')

using the above line some of the data from Iface(ports) column is misplaced in HWaddress column for example eth0.1 and eth0.2 should be in Iface(ports) column but they are shifted to HWaddress column.